# Best way to read a file into buffer if you need to check middle symbol of word

Tags: c

I want to ask what's the best way of reading a file (pref. using buffer) if I will need to throw out words which middle symbol is a number. (There can be more than one space between words). The text file could look like this "asd4ggt gklk6k   k77k 345k ll4l 7" so I need to throw out "asd4ggt" and "7" (I don't need to throw out "k77k" because it's even number of symbols so there isn't middle symbol). In words symbols can be from 0 to 9, A to Z, a to z (only simple English alphabet)

I think of reading a text file word by word: read one word into buffer if it has even number of symbols then write it to file but if it has odd number of symbols then I have to check if its' middle symbol is a number and if it is I skip this word and go to the next word. 
Is this a right way of thinking how to complete this task?

Comment: Where are "words example"? You should show us an Example of what you tried and what you need.

Comment: Those spaces are always four spaces? If so just read them and Update a separate variable and remove the first letters until you rich a space and after that you need to remove the letters/numbers after the last space.

Comment: `and I don't need to throw out "k77k"` You didn't say nothing about `gklk6k`!

Comment: What exactly is the difference beteween `asd4ggt` and `gklk6k` ? you mean that `asd4ggt` has `3` letters followed by a number and then another `3` letters? I'm not follow you at all. I see that you need `k77k` this mean you have the same number of letters before and after the number `77` which is `k + k`

Comment: "gklk6k" doesn't have a middle symbol because it has even number of symbols so I have to write "gklk6k" to a text file and "asd4ggt" has 7 symbols which means 4th symbol is the middle one and it is a number "4" so I need to throw out this word. k77k is the same as "gklk6k" it doesn't have a middle symbol.

Comment: OK.  And if you'll have this `g666k`? you need it or you throw it?

Comment: `tk4lk` this has a middle simbol, the `4`, or I still get it wrong

Comment: I throw "g666k" out. Yes "tk4lk" has a middle symbol, the 4.

Comment: So you throw `g666k` and `g676k` not?

Comment: I throw "g676k" out too because its' middle symbol is third, the 7, and it is a number

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea what are you talking about. Hope there is someone else here who can help you. I thought you need [something like this](http://ideone.com/OBat8Y). For me this `"tk4lk"` means that `4` is a middle symbol and its a number. or you mean when you say `third` that here `g676k` has `3` numbers?  ==>> `676`

Comment: if input file is "g66k g676k tk4lk k77k gklk6k" output file should look "g66k k77k gklk6k"

Comment: 1. if word has even number of symbols like g66k (4 symbols), k77k (4), gklk6k (6) or pk (2) I write those words to output file. 2. if word has odd number of symb. like tk4lk (5), tkl (3) I check if its' middle symbol is a number tk4lk is a number, the 4 and tkl is a letter, the k, so I write to output tkl and not tk4lk

Comment: let me see if I got it. This `"g66k g676k tk4lk k77k gklk6k"` means `4 5 5 4 6`. And you need to check only words which their length is even (4 - 4 -6) and then to see if they have a symbol?

Comment: `so I write to output tkl and not tk4lk ` I'm almost there, why `tkl` and not `tklk`?

Comment: check words which their length is odd and then to see if in the middle of the word is a letter or a number

Comment: Yes, but why `tkl` and not `tklk` ?

Comment: because tk4lk has a number in the middle so i throw the whole word not only a number

Comment: Now you say you throw  the whole word, but earlier you said `so I write to output tkl and not tk4lk`. I'm lost here. I was asking you, why why `tkl` and not `tklk`?

Comment: Oh, I meant if there was two seperate words tkl and tk4lk

Comment: This means that when you have this `tk4lk` you write this `tklk`? but when you have this `t4k4k` you write this `t4k4k`, because `k` is middle and is not a number?

Comment: this means if I have the word "tk4lk" I don't write it to output and if I have the word "tkl" I write "tkl" to output.

Comment: This means that [something like this you need](http://ideone.com/oy4dKo)?

Comment: Yes! But how to do that if there are more than one word in input file?

Comment: Please check my Answer.

Comment: Just read it one more time carefully, now I understand how to do that. Thank you very much for your help and patience!!

Comment: Please accept [my Answer then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576958/best-way-to-read-a-file-into-buffer-if-you-need-to-check-middle-symbol-of-word/40578211#40578211).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of your comment we came to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int evenCheck(const char *ptr);
size_t middleCheck(const char *ptr);

int main(void){
    const char *ptr = "t4k4k";
    size_t middle = middleCheck(ptr);

    if( evenCheck(ptr) == 0){
        printf("Output to file the word %s\n",ptr);
    }else{
        if ( isdigit(ptr[middle]) ){
            printf("Ignoring the word %s, because has the number %c in the middle\n",ptr, ptr[middle]);
        }else{
            printf("Output to file the word %s, because the middle is %c which is a Letter\n",ptr, ptr[middle]);
        }
    }
}

int evenCheck(const char *ptr){
    size_t len = strlen(ptr);

    if ( (len % 2) ){
       return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

size_t middleCheck(const char *ptr){
    size_t middle = strlen(ptr) / 2;

    return middle;
}
```

Output:

```
Output to file the word t4k4k, because the middle is k which is a Letter
```

Now you were asking about how to do this if the file has more than one word.

Well one option will be to save the file in a [Multi-Dimensional array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm) or read the whole file.

I'm sure you can do it, if not come back with another Question.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of data, and what you plan to do with it. If it's a small enough file that sits in a single buffer, just load the file and then *throw out* whichever parts you don't want from the buffer.

If the data needs to be loaded into a data structure other than a flat buffer, then you'll need to process the input, probably line-by-line, building the structure and throwing out what you don't need as you go.

Note that the standard file routines can read a byte or line of text efficiently (they still use a larger buffer internally).

Other than that, you're question really isn't that clear.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define which encoding is your text file using. On most operating systems, it would be [UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/) (so [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) characters can take several bytes each).

Then, the notion of word is probably (human) language specific. I'm not sure it would be the same in English (BTW, `gklk6k`  is *not* an English word, it does not appear in any English dictionnary), in ancient Greek, in Russian, in Japanese, in Chinese. Notice that the notion of letter is not as simple as you would imagine (Unicode has much more letters than `A` ... `Z` & `a` ... `z`; my family name in Russian is `Старынкевич` and all these letters are outside of `A` ... `Z`  & `a` ... `z`, and they need more than one byte each). And what about [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)? [Greek diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_diacritics)? What exactly are words for you, how can they be separated? What about punctuation?

If your system provides it, I would use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read a line and have a loop around that. Then process every line. Splitting it into words is itself interesting. You could use some UTF-8 library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) (from [GTK](http://gtk.org/)) etc etc...

In other words, you should **define *first* what your input can be** (and a few examples *don't* constitute a definition). Perhaps you could specify the possible valid input using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation. Maybe reading more about [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) & [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques is relevant.

Comment: In my situation words can consist symbols from 0 to 9, A to Z, a to z (only simple English alphabet).

Comment: That should go in your question (you should edit it), and what about delimiters or punctuations?